# Can trinomial trees be used to model subdiffusion?

Tags: brownian-motion

I am modeling a sub-diffusive process where the particles follow geometric Brownian motion (GBM) with movement occurring after randomly distributed waiting times.

I have set this up as a simulation to explore different distributions of waiting times, however the process is inefficient.

My question: can trinomial trees be used to model sub-diffusive GBM? Since the path steps involve up/down movements or no change - was wondering if the waiting time can be built in by increasing the probability of no change in a specific way.

Comment: probably, but a more specific description of the process would help